# Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled in xcode log

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is the following message when my app loads have any cause for concern.  If I disabled `FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled` does that have any consequence? Not much info about this online.

> Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist

Comment: Does anyone know how to squelch the message from showing in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No concern; yes, is used for analytics (bolding mine):

> Sets the current screen name, which specifies the current visual context in your app. This **helps identify the areas in your app where users spend their time** and how they interact with your app.

[FIRAnalytics +setScreenName:screenClass:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics#setscreennamescreenclass)

Answer (score 8):

Set a new key-value pair on info.plist `FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled = NO`.

More information follow the below picture

[image]

Comment: That didn't works for me. Maybe something extra to do?

Comment: @CGN what worked for you? I'm also having same issue. plist entry is not solving this issue. I'm using Xcode 11.1 and XS device running on iOS 13.1.2.

Comment: @user1947894: By setting FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled = NO in the info.plist (like shown in the screenshot above) I was able to turn off the screen reporting by Firebase. That's what was working for me. Hope, that helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing which screen the user is on, helps identify the areas in your app where users spend their time and how they interact with your app.

If you disable automatic screen reporting, the Firebase Analytics reports will not automatically show the screen the user is on anymore. You can still call the [setScreenName:screenClass: method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics#setscreennamescreenclass) to report the screen that the user is on.

Comment: So this is just for analytics reporting? Can be ignored?

Comment: Yes, it can be ignored by setting `FirebaseScreenReportingEnable` to `false` in `Info.plist` of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set login "vc" as initial viewcontroller. It helped me at least.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To help others that run into this issue, could you add a little more information on how you figured this out, or an explanation of how it helps?