# FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled is disabling even my calls

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I've set `FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled` to `NO` in `Info.plist`, because I wanted to handle, myself, the `setScreenName:screenClass:` calls.

But Firebase doesn't allow me to call it.

This message is logged at the console:

```
 <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031000] Ignoring call to setScreenName:screenClass:. Screen reporting is disabled.
```

I've followed [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666124/firebase-automatic-screen-reporting-is-enabled-in-xcode-log):

> If you disable automatic screen reporting, the Firebase Analytics reports will not automatically show the screen the user is on anymore. You can still call the setScreenName:screenClass: method to report the screen that the user is on.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, how did you solve this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46916247)

> I got the answer from Firebase that On iOS, they support automatic + manual screen reporting or no screen reporting at all. Google Analytics for Firebase does NOT support the case of manual-only screen reporting. The plist flag **FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled** has been renamed to **FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled** to reduce that confusion. Note that the value must be a Boolean and not a String. If it doesn't work as you expected, you can disable screen reporting completely by adding to Info.plist the flag **FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled** with a Boolean value of NO.

But, for me **FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled** working. I didn't change the new name in `info.plist` as **FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled**

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible to manually track screens with new API
Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65501488/8258130