# Disable auto-activity tracking in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I'm wondering, are there any way to disable analytics auto activity tracking?
I have view hierarchy based on fragments and there are few cases:

1. Activity that have one fragment always.
2. Activity that can have different fragments as root.
3. Activity with root fragment, that contains ViewPager with other fragments.

I use such a code in fragments from Firebase docs to track custom screens:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(getActivity(), "some_fragment_1", null);
```

In first case, I want to track only root fragment.
In second case, I want to track only each fragment that becomes root.
In third case, I want to track only each fragment that becomes visible in ViewPager.

And, the problem is, that I don't want to track Activities at all, but unfortunately, Firebase do it on its own - as a result of that, my statistics looks weird, like:

> SomeActivity 50%
>
> some_fragment_1 30%
>
> some_fragment_2 20%

I dont't need activity in this statistics, because, fragment statistics already includes it.

So, is there any way to disable activity tracking?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/370

Not sure if you've seen that, but other people are also asking for the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

Now it's possible with new API to manually track screens.

**Can disable auto-tracking**

On iOS, set FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in your info.plist. On Android, set google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled to false in your manifest.

**Manual Tracking**

**iOS**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // After enough time has passed to make this screen view significant.
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [
        AnalyticsParameterScreenName: screenName!,
        AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: screenClass!,
        MyAppAnalyticsParameterFitnessCategory: category!
    ])
}
```

**Android**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // After enough time has passed to make this screen view significant.
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, screenClass);
    bundle.putString(MyAppAnalyticsConstants.Param.TOPIC, topic);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);
}
```

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2225 does not seem to work (anymore), disabling screen tracking

Comment: How to do this on web? `firebase-js-sdk`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is rather a hack, but seems to be working with latest firebase analytics. The idea is that, Firebase Analytics uses `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` internally on each activity declared in the manifest, so disabling that way disables auto-activity reporting.

Place that code in each root `Activity` you are using.

```
@Override
public void registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback) {
    // com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl for firebase-core:17.1.0, play-services-measurement-impl:17.1.0
    if (!callback.getClass().getName().startsWith("com.google.android.gms.measurement.")){
            super.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(callback);
    }
}
```

Credits for finding that goes to @liudongmiao on https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/370.

Answer (score 0):

To disable screen auto-tracking in Firebase Analytics 17.5.0, I had to catch callback registrations in my Application class, not in individual activities, and the callback class name has changed again:

```
    @Override
    public void registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback) {
        if (!callback.getClass().getName().startsWith("com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.")){
            super.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(callback);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, contrary to what Google's documentation states (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#SCREEN_VIEW), I wasn't able to manually tag screen views by logging the event `FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW`. For now I've resorted to logging screen views with a custom event.